# Is this server vulnerable to SSL renegotiation vulnerability?

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssl, apache-2.4

I have an apache server and I want to check if the server is vulnerable to SSL renegotiation vulnerability. I executed this code:

```
openssl s_client  -connect ****:443
```

And there is this line in the output:

> Secure Renegotiation IS supported

and when I try this:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
R
```

The output is like this:

> ```
> depth=1 C = FR, O = KEYNECTIS, CN = CLASS 2 KEYNECTIS CA
> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
> read:errno=0
> ```

Is this server vulnerable? Is this the correct way to discover this type of vulnerability?

Comment: If the server is externally accessible, I would recommend running the SSL labs server test against it: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not externally accessible. Is there a desktop tool that I can check the server against it?

Comment: Then at the risk of asking a silly question: why does it matter whether it's vulnerable to SSL renegotiation?

Comment: It will be accessible soon. It's in the security test phase.

Comment: Fair enough. You're basically there anyway - I've linked a useful reference below.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.contextis.com/blog/manually-testing-ssl-tls-weaknesses) is a very useful reference page.

However, you are basically there - you should find a line in your output from the command you ran, similar to the following if renegotiation is not supported:

`Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported`

Comment: Is it safe when renegotiation is not supported or when it's supported? Is my server safe now?